# Load video files into HTML as they are dynamically created with PHP

Tags: php, html5-video

I have a folder of videos (ex 001.mp4, 002.mp4...) and their posters (ex 001.jpg, 002.jpg...) that is populated by a script that processes a user's uploaded clips.  The folder *will* have all the posters when this php file accesses it, but not all the clips yet (usually takes < 20 seconds to process the clips).  What I'd like to do is load up the clips as they become available (to avoid 404 errors), so I've written this code below.  It loops on the poster files and checks for its paired mp4.  If it doesn't find one, it sleeps for a second.  Seems good in theory, but in reality all I get is a page loading wait until all clips are available.  What gives?  If anyone has a better approach to this problem, I'm all ears.

```
$folder='sakjhd87HA';
$vidindex = 1;
foreach ($files as $file) {
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($ext == "jpg") {
                $poster    = $file;
                $clip      = basename($file, '.' . $ext) . '.mp4';
                $width     = shell_exec("ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_streams $folder/$file | grep width= | grep -v coded | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\n'");
                $height    = shell_exec("ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_streams $folder/$file | grep height= | grep -v coded | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d '\n'");
                $pad       = 70;
                $divwidth  = $width + $pad . 'px';
                $divheight = $height + $pad . 'px';
                $clipcpath = $folder . '/' . $clip;
                while (!file_exists ($clipcpath)) {
                        sleep(1);
                }
                echo "<div style=\"height:$divheight; width:$divwidth; display: block; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #404040;\" ><p>Clip #$vidindex</p><video class=\"clip\" id=\"videos$vidindex\" controls=\"controls\" loop=\"loop\" preload=\"none\" poster=\"$folder/$poster\" width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"";
                if ($vidindex == 1) {
                        echo " autoplay>\n";
                } else {
                        echo ">\n";
                }
                echo "<source src=\"$folder/$clip\"/>\n";
                echo "</video></div>\n";
                $vidindex = $vidindex + 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code waits for all the clips to appear in the folder before exiting the main loop, so a client will get nothing untill all vids are available. If you want to display something before all vids are processed, you would rather have to handle each clip with an Ajax request doing basically what your code does, but on a per-clip basis.

Comment: Typically half the clips are already available when the script runs, which means that it would have gotten through the loop and echo'd the html for those clips before pausing.  I suppose I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this HTML is delivered to the browser.  Does the PHP script run in its entirety before any HTML is written to the browser?

Comment: Yes it does. You won't get anything but a "loading..." status in your browser until the PHP script is done.

Comment: In theory, what would trigger the ajax request?  In best practice, should it be bound to something like scrolling down the page?

Comment: @UltrasoundJelly, I'd suggest the jQuery library (and reading up on it) and using `$(document).ready(function() { /* ajax code in here */ });`

Comment: Thanks.  I think my plan will be to loop on the jpgs and only show whats mp4 files are available at the time.  If they're not all present I'll place a button at the bottom that will call the ajax request for the remaining files.

Comment: You can launch all requests as soon as you generate the page. Start by generating posters, that will be replaced with videos as Ajax responses start coming. Classically you can limit the number of requests to the visible part of the page.